# Can I get information from a table inside a form in mvc binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `<form>` element, inside the form I have a table with inputs inside `<td>`, something like:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
    <th class="a"> @Model.header1 </th>
    <th class="b"> @Model.header2 </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="c" value"100" /></td>
    <td><input class="c" value"200" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Is it possible for me to read the information about the table, that is not the input values from a custom binder? More precisely I would like to read header 1 and 2 class and text.

I know that to read the value of the input I can use `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[name]` , but I can't really find much information about anything else.

EDIT: Just to be clear, my goal is to obtain this information inside an mvc binder. 
EDIT2: Also yes, I'm using model to create view data. Sorry it wasn't clear before, I've modified the example

Comment: Do you want to read or write (output) it? Since you're using ASP.NET MVC, have a look at using the [HtmlHelper Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx)

Comment: @RickvandenBosch I'm trying to save data from the form to the server.

Comment: @Xyzk - I've just seen the edit to your post. Are you using models to render the view data? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @Wheels73 I do, I just tried to simplify it in the question. I will edit it momentarily

Comment: A form only posts the name/value pairs of its successful form controls, so short answer is no (although what is the point - your already know what those values are on the server and they cannot be edited by the user)

Comment: @Xyzk If you're saving data from the form to the server, why would you need to know what's in the header of a table column? Most important hint: use a ```Model``` and the HtmlHelper Class I pointed out earlier. On your question: give the inputs names that look like the headers of the columns to find out what the values you're receiving are for: those names are bound to the key value pair you're receiving.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch so you are suggesting I should save the data that cannot be changed inside the helper class, and then read it during the binding from the helper? I will try it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke hmm if you post this as an answer I will most likely accept. And to answer your question why- In my view it can be changes, as I added some jquery buttons that allow user to change class, which I wanted to save

Comment: What do you mean _change class_? And what is the information that you want to send to the controller?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean using jquery button users can change the header `<th class="a">` to `<th class="b">`, which changes the display. Basing on this information I want to change the information that will be saved in my model.

Comment: If you update your question to explain that (including your script), then an answer can be added showing how to do that (but I'm about to sign off for an hour or so)